# R - Function or script to populate a dataframe with accumulative partial calculations (not cum sum)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

This is quite an specific challenge. Let's say I have this table, think of a typical bank database (working with data.table by the way):

```
customer_id; month; balance
1;1;100
1;2;110
1;3;140
1;4;70
```

I need a script or function that returns, for every row, the ratio relative to the max historical balance so far for each customer.

```
customer_id; month; balance; ratio
1;1;100;1       # 1 because 100 balance is both the current datapoint and the max value so far
1;2;110;1.1     # 1.1 because 110 balance is 1.1 of the prior max value, 100
1;3;140;1.27    # 1.27 because it's 140 divided by the prior max value, 110
1;4;70;0.5      # 0.5 because it's 70 divided by the prior max value, 140
```

I know some dplyr or data.table methods can work with cumulative calculations, such as cumsum.
However this has a twist I can't quite find online.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr` using `cummax` (the cumulative maximum) and `lag` (to get previous values) fairly easily

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  group_by(customer_id) %>% 
  mutate(ratio = balance/lag(cummax(balance), default=first(balance)))

#   customer_id month balance ratio
#         <int> <int>   <int> <dbl>
# 1           1     1     100  1   
# 2           1     2     110  1.1 
# 3           1     3     140  1.27
# 4           1     4      70  0.5
```

where

```
dd <- read.table(text="
customer_id; month; balance
1;1;100
1;2;110
1;3;140
1;4;70", sep=";", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This code does what I need, but it now needs and extra tweak to make it failsafe for datasets with NAs. Could you please take a look at the new thread I opened? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58844776/adding-na-omit-in-mutate-with-lag-and-cummax-causes-error-column-must-be-len) . Thanks!